# Get data from MySQL in Form 1 pass to Form 2

Tags: c#, mysql

A basic code to connect to MySQL from my Form 1

```
string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionSvtrings["MySQL"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection sqlconn = new MySqlConnection(mainconn);
            string sqlquery = "select * from grade where ....";
            MySqlCommand sqlcomm = new MySqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            ........
```

In my table have 3 columns : ID, Class_name, Local.

How can I get data from these and pass them to Form 2? 
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

you can litterally copy and paste man. since the database is outside your projects scope, its accessible from anywhere if you use the right connection string. meaning its not form specific, just do exactly what you did in your first form.